# Scroll edittext in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` which its items include `EditText`. Each edittext has multiline but the height of the row is limited. Thus, I need to scroll in the edittext. I search many solutions but it hasn't been successful.

Answer (score 0):

The touchEvent in this case is handled by ListView and it is not passed to the children. You can override the **onInterceptTouchEvent** and return false from it and then the touch event will be passed to the children(EditText).

```
public class myListView extends ListView {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Note: If you pass the touchEvent to child you will not be able to scroll the ListView. So depending on your requirement you have to decide when to return false from onInterceptTouchEvent.

reference: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Comment: When I use your method, the listview can't scroll. 
I want scroll like this:
- If the edittext has multiline which need to scroll to watch all, it will scroll inside the edittext. When it scroll to the end of the edittext, the scroll will be returned to the listview.
- If I scroll out of the edittext (the edittext that I start to scroll), scroll is also returned to the listview

Comment: I am not sure but i think the following might work.
1. Create every List item as your own custom view.
2. For every custom view except the EditText (for which you want to handle the touchEvent) pass the touchEvent to ListView.

Comment: At this time, each item of the listview include edittext, imagebutton and textview. If I touch on view except edittext, I can scroll the listview normally. The problem just happens when I touch on the area contains edittext

Comment: Are you not able to scroll just the EditText while rest of the functionality is working? Note that in case of EditText you have to call super.onTouchEvent also for handling the touch event.
Can you share your code after these changes?

Comment: Not yet. It's still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom listview I had the same problem which I solved using following code.

```
public class Mylistview extends ListView{

        public Mylistview(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

         public Mylistview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
            }

            public Mylistview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            final int action = ev.getAction();
            switch (action)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false" );
                        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                        break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false" );
                        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                        break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false" );
                        return false;

                default: Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action ); break;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction() );
             return true;
        }

}
```